# Javascript backgroundImage slideshow with bubbles

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Please am trying to create image slide show with background image and bubbles that changes with the image, which was working very until i added mouseover and mouseout eventListeners. on mouseover the slide show stops and starts on mouseout.

The problem here is that after the mouseout event is called, the images seems to be showing randomly instead of sequentially. That is if bubble 1 is active, instead of displaying image 1, it picks maybe image 4 or 5. please can anyone help me out. Thanks.

Here is my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bubble 4</title>

<style type="text/css">

#bubblebox{
height: 550px;
width: 1200px;
border:2px solid black;
margin: 50px auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: -5;
background-size: cover;
transition:background-image 0.2s;
transition: opacity 0.3s linear 0s;
}
#bubbles{
    height: 0px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;

}
#bubbles div{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border: 2px solid green;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 310px;
    color:#fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#heading{
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 500px
}
#arrow_right, #arrow_left, #arrow_middle{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 -10px 0 0px;
    top: 200px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}

#arrow_right2, #arrow_left2, #arrow_middle2{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: .5s;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 -10px 0 0px;
    top: 200px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#arrow_right2:hover, #arrow_left2:hover, #arrow_middle2:hover{
box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#arrow_right:hover, #arrow_left:hover, #arrow_middle:hover{
box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var bubble_Array;
var bubble_i = 0;
var intrval;
var ba;
var bi =0;
var intr;


var man = ['url(imags/ParLour.jpg', 'url(imags/767.jpg', 'url(imags/7series.jpg', 'url(imags/02.jpg', 'url(imags/BedRoom.jpg', 'url(imags/30.jpg', 'url(imags/volks.jpg', 'url(imags/sports.jpg', 'url(imags/real.jpg', 'url(imags/portable.jpg', 'url(imags/perspective.jpg', 'url(imags/green.jpg', 'url(imags/fantom.jpg', 'url(imags/fantom2.jpg', 'url(imags/elegance.jpg', 'url(imags/bridge.jpg', 'url(imags/BMW.jpg', 'url(imags/interior.jpg','url(imags/3Dcar007.jpg'];


function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function bubbleMain(bi){
    bubble_i++;
    if(bubble_i == man.length){
        bubble_i = 0;
    }
    _('bubblebox').style.opacity = 0;
    for (var i =0; i < ba.length; i ++){
        ba[i].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,.1)";
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        _('bubblebox').style.backgroundImage = man[bubble_i];
        ba[bi].style.background = "red";
        _("bubblebox").style.opacity = 1;
    }, 500);
}
function bubbleSlide(){

    ba = _('bubbles').children;
    _('bubblebox').style.backgroundImage = man[bubble_i];
    ba[bi].style.backgroundColor = 'red';


    bi++;
    if (bi == ba.length){
        bi =0;
    }
bubbleMain(bi);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    ba = _('bubbles').children;
    _('bubblebox').style.backgroundImage = man[bubble_i];
    ba[bi].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    intrval = setInterval(bubbleSlide, 2000);
    })
//This is where i added mouseover
window.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    clearInterval(intrval);
})
//I am suspecting this line od codes.
window.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    intrval = setInterval(bubbleSlide, 2000);
})


</script>




<div id="bubblebox">
    <div id="bubbles">
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(0)">1</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(1)">2</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(2)">3</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(3)">4</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(4)">5</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(5)">6</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(6)">7</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(7)">8</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(8)">9</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(9)">10</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(10)">11</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(11)">12</div>
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(12)">13</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(13)">14</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(14)">15</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(15)">16</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(16)">17</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(17)">18</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(18)">19</div> 
        <div onclick="bubbleMain(19)">20</div>
    </div>
    <div id="heading"></div>
<div id="arrow_right"></div>
<div id="arrow_middle"></div>
<div id="arrow_left"></div>

<div id="arrow_right2"></div>
<div id="arrow_middle2"></div>
<div id="arrow_left2"></div>
<div id="bubblecontent"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update your question and use correct formatting. Thank you.

Comment: It would be great if you can add snippet!

Comment: In the bubbleSlide() function. The first three lines of codes was copied from window.addEventListener("load"), function(). For mouseout function to initialize them. Please is there any other way to walk around it. I really need help.